# is this code still supported on php version 5.4.24

Tags: php

When my server updated to PHP version 5.4.24,
I've encountered some errors on my script using this code

```
.=
```

sample code are

```
$test .= 'hello';
$test .= 'to';
$test .= 'all';
echo $test;
```

I got undefined variable test.
Everything is working when my server PHP version is 5.2.10

Is `.=` still supported on PHP version 5.4.24

Is there any alternative code for this? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: You would get `undefined variable test` on your 5.2.10 PHP as well, it's just that you were either not reporting errors, or not displaying them.  If `error_reporting` was turned up to `E_ALL`, you would've gotten the error there too.  Initialize it with `$test = ''` before appending to it with `.=`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Always when developing code, on any PHP version, make sure `error_reporting` is turned all the way up and you are using `display_errors` to show them on screen as you code. Fix _all_ of them, including notices and warnings.  Set those in php.ini or at runtime with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If only WordPress plug-in authors would do this, it would make the times I work in WordPress for clients so much less painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's related to this: [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

If you do

```
$test='';
$test .= 'hello';
$test .= 'to';
$test .= 'all';
echo $test;
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks tecbrat this solved my problem, i thought it was version of php.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you would need to do. Just use = the first time.

```
$test = 'hello';
$test .= 'to';
$test .= 'all';
echo $test;
```